# CoreData mapping with RestKit will sync automatically?

Tags: objective-c, restkit

When we use CoreData mapping with RestKit, will it sync automatically in time periods? I mean when server database is updated, will it reflect in our local database automatically? Or will it sync only by calling appropriate code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RestKit only does anything when you tell it to. It will not automatically poll your server to check for changes.

Comment: i dont think so because RestKit network reachability checking happens periodically. i thought CoreData syncing also might be same.